# Mocking child components only for specific test in react tests using jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

My App (root component) Looks something like this

```
<div>
<button>Click Me</button>
<ChildComponent/>
</div>
```

In my test file for App component (App.test.js), I have two tests. I wish to mock the ChildComponent in 1 test but use the actualy Child Component implementation in the 2nd test.

Putting a jest.mock("./components/ChildComponent") at the top in App.test.js mocks it for all tests in the file.

I would greatly appreciate if you can respond with a small working example.

Thanks in advance.

```
describe("Tests for App Component", ()=>{

it("Test 1",()=>{
// Use Actual Child Component implmeentation in this test  
})

it("Test 2",()=>{
// Use mocked Child Component here as the assertions are not related to the Child Component here, assertions only check the button and other components in App.js
})
})
```

Comment: have you tried calling `.mockClear()` on your mock after your first test?

Comment: ```
jest.mock("./components/ChildComponent",() => () => <div/>)
```
If I mock at the top like this, how shall I do a mockClear please? Do you have a working example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is split test file into 2. So you will be able to mock `jest.mock('./components/ChildComponent',`  in one, and use real child in another.

Alternative is trying to make `jest.doMock` and `jest.unmock` working for your case, but I'm not sure this will work. And it would definitely make test's code messy and confusing without any real value. Who cares, whether it's the only test file per component or two?